# Javascript how to end a function

Tags: javascript

There are 4 horses on my track. https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WUW3.png

I press start and the horses are supposed to complete a lap. I have managed to make them go around the first corner and make them stop at the second corner like so https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlqfA.png

Heres my code for the white horse, my problem is that the functions are calling each other constantly and due to this I am unable to go around the second corner due to

```
positionTop >= window.innerHeight * 0.84 - 50
```

from horse1 function running and preventing the horse from going left.

```js
var interval = 0;

function startRace() {
    var raceTimer = setInterval(100);
    var raceActive = true;
    loop();
}

function loop() {
    interval = setInterval(horse1, 10);
    interval = setInterval(horse2, 10);
    interval = setInterval(horse3, 10);
    interval = setInterval(horse4, 10);
}

function horse1() {
    var horse1 = document.getElementById('horse1');
    var positionLeft = horse1.offsetLeft;
    var positionTop = horse1.offsetTop
    horse1.className = 'horse runRight'

    if (positionLeft >= window.innerWidth * 0.84 - 50) {
        horse1down();
    } else {
        horse1.style.left = positionLeft + 1 + 'px';
    }
}

function horse1down() {
    var horse1 = document.getElementById('horse1');
    var positionTop = horse1.offsetTop;
    horse1.className = 'horse runDown'

    if (positionTop >= window.innerHeight * 0.85 - 50) {
        horse1left()
    } else {
        horse1.style.top = positionTop + 1 + 'px';
    }
}

function horse1left() {
    var horse1 = document.getElementById('horse1');
    var positionLeft = horse1.offsetLeft
    horse1.style.left = positionLeft - 1 + 'px';
    horse1.className = 'horse runLeft'
}

function myLoadFunction() {
    var startButton = document.getElementById('start');
    startButton.addEventListener('click', startRace);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', myLoadFunction);
```

What I have tried:

I have tried clear intervals but I might be doing them wrong.

```js
function horse1down() {
    var horse1 = document.getElementById('horse1');
    var positionTop = horse1.offsetTop;
    horse1.className = 'horse runDown'
    if (positionTop >= window.innerHeight * 0.85 - 50) {
        horse1left()
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = setInterval(horse1, 10);
    } else {
        horse1.style.top = positionTop + 1 + 'px';
    }
}
```

Comment: You're overriding the interval variable, you should have a separate `interval` for each horse otherwise you will only be able to clear one interval.

Comment: Could you show me a small example please? im struggling to understand >you should have a separate interval for each horse

Comment: `function loop() {
    interval1 = setInterval(horse1, 10);
    interval2 = setInterval(horse2, 10);
    interval3 = setInterval(horse3, 10);
    interval4 = setInterval(horse4, 10);
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting variable `interval`.Create an array with 4 different intervals and you will be able to clear them separately.

In general its better to use `setTimeout` insead of `setInterval`. You can easily rewrite `setInterval` function to safer `setTimeout`. `setInterval` doesn't care whether the callback is still running or not.
In some cases, the function might need longer than the interval time to finish execution. What would happen is that you'll end up with a bunch of queued requests that may not necessarily return in order.